# Prove that subset(sequence) is bounded below

Tags: real-analysis

Let X be a nonempty subset of the real numbers, which is bounded below and, in fact, $u:=\inf X>0$.
How to prove that:

$a)$the set $\frac{1}{X}:=\{\frac{1}{x}: x \in X\}$ is bounded below;

$b)$ $\sup (\frac{1}{X})=\frac{1}{u}$.

I'm new to real analysis and would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: "...the set $\frac{1}{X}:=\{\frac{1}{x}: x \in X\}$ is bounded below;" Is this a typo; do you *instead* intend ...bounded **above**?  This comment/question is *motivated* by the speculative relationship between parts (a) and (b) of your query.

Comment: Try to use the definition of $sup$ from set theory, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum

Comment: @user2661923 I edited your post and fixed the typo, you will see this in a moment

Comment: @OrShahar "I edited your post and fixed the typo,...". [1] It is not my query. [2] I don't see any editing. [3] My comment/question is directed to the OP (i.e. original poster); that is, the OP needs to **personally clarify** the OP's intended query.